# inserting table through directive

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to insert a table through a directive in Angular1.3 -

controller

```
var studentControllerModule = angular.module('studentDetailApp.controllers', []); 
/*StudentController: controller for students*/ 
studentControllerModule.controller('StudentController', function ($scope) { 
$scope.studentList = [ ....];
 });
```

directive

```
angular.module('studentDetailApp.directives',[]).directive('studentDirective', function () {
    return {
        template: '<table><thead><tr> <th>NAME</th><th>COUNTRY</th></tr></thead><tbody> <tr ng-repeat="aStudent in studentList"><td>{{aStudent.name }}</td><td>{{aStudent.country }}</td></tr></tbody></table>'};
});
```

index.html

```
    <html lang="en" ng-app="studentDetailApp">
<head>
    <title>AngularJS Partial example</title>
    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/directives.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="StudentController"> 
    <div studentDirective></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I get no exception  - but I do not see the table either.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you add a link function to your directive and console.log studentList does it exist? Or use the batarang chrome add-on

Comment: where is your ng-app?

Comment: I don't see any `<table>` anywhere.

Comment: removed it to test alternatives.Placed it back in the directive template now - no impact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were missing your ng-app, directives need to be normalized in the html:
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive
Modified HTML:

```
<body ng-app="studentDetailApp">
    <div ng-controller="StudentController"> 
        <div class='a' student-directive></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Modified JS:

```
var app = angular.module('studentDetailApp', []);

app.controller('StudentController', function ($scope) { 
    $scope.studentList = ['nate', 'john', 'seth'];
 });

app.directive('studentDirective', function () {
    return {
        template: '<table><thead><tr> <th>NAME</th><th>COUNTRY</th></tr></thead><tbody> <tr ng-repeat="aStudent in studentList"><td>{{aStudent.name }}</td><td>{{aStudent.country }}</td></tr></tbody></table>'
    };
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cn3otfa6/3/

Comment: Found the issue was owing to the directive not being named correctly on the index.html( - case).